# incompatible block pointer types initializing 'void(^)(struct ALAssetsGroup *, BOOL *)'with an expression of type

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks, alassetslibrary, alasset

I saw several people on SO have been using this code successfully.  But I got the incompatible block pointer error:

Incompatible block pointer types initializing

```
void(^)(struct ALAssetsGroup *, BOOL *)
```

with an expression of type

```
void(^)(ALAsset *, NSUInteger, BOOL *)
```

Any hints?  (EDIT with complete code)

```
    ALAssetsLibrary *library =[[ALAssetsLibrary alloc]init];
    void (^assetEnumerator)(struct ALAsset *, NSUInteger, BOOL *) = ^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop){
    if(result != NULL) {
                NSLog(@"See Asset: %@", result);

            }
        };

    void (^assetGroupEnumerator)(struct ALAssetsGroup *, BOOL *) =  ^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
            if(group != nil) {NSLog(@"dont See Asset: ");
                [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:assetEnumerator];
            }
        };

    [library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAlbum
                               usingBlock:assetGroupEnumerator
                             failureBlock: ^(NSError *error) {
                                 NSLog(@"Failure");
                             }];
```

[image]

Comment: Post more of your code -- the snippets you have there seem fine.

Comment: If you could tell us what line of code the compiler is barking at, it would really help us help you.

Comment: Added image that shows error messages.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK, newbie at blocks... but I found another example of an asset group enumerator block on here, and it didn't have `struct` in the declaration.   I tried removing it from the code above, and it still works fine and doesn't have the error message.  Hopefully someone who understands `struct` better can explain?

try changing this line:

```
void (^assetGroupEnumerator)(struct ALAssetsGroup *, BOOL *) 
            = ^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop)
```

to this:

```
void (^assetGroupEnumerator)(ALAssetsGroup *, BOOL *) 
            = ^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop)
```

I think the bottom line is that the `ALAssetsLibrary enumerateGroupsWithTypes: usingBlock:` expects a block looking like `(ALAssetsGroup *, BOOL *)` not `(struct ALAssetsGroup *, BOOL *)`.

Comment: I chose this one to be the answer just because it said .. removing struct and it still works fine!  So, did I.  The interesting thing was that even though with the "red" error, it compiled and ran normally.  I just want to find out why others have no problem but mine!!!

Answer (score 3):

The difference between the expected and the actual type is just the work *struct*, i.e. `struct ALAsset*` vs. `ALAsset*`. (In your textual description it looks like a mismatch between `ALAsset` and `ALAssetGroups`, but I think you made a mistake in copying the error message.)

I don't quite understand where these differences come from (possibly due to the use of C++ somewhere?).

Anyway, the best solution is to use the type definition `ALAssetsGroupEnumerationResultsBlock` or `ALAssetsLibraryGroupsEnumerationResultsBlock` respectively, e.g.:

```
ALAssetsGroupEnumerationResultsBlock assetEnumerator = ^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop){
    if (result != NULL) {
            NSLog(@"See Asset: %@", result);
        }
    };
```

Comment: Yeah, I found out it as well.  Thanks for reply.